# What is the vertical scale set for this scope screen?

Tags: oscilloscope

In a paper I came across I was confused interpreting the vertical scale. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Is each big square 2V or 100mV? (What does 2V and 100mV at the bottom mean?)
In the zoom the voltage increases in stairstep fashion. I need to know how much it increments per step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 V per vertical division and 50 ms per horizontal division, so your signal would be 4 Vpp.

Can you use measure or vertical/horizontal lines in your scope? If yes, use them to "draw" in your curve and get an exact answer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I was thinking so. So 2θx in the screen shot is 4V correct?

Comment: @ty_1917 Yes. Any horizontal bar function on your scope? Or this is not yours?

Comment: No it was from a paper. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As winny has answered, the scope is set for 2V per division vertically and 50 msec per division horizontally.

So your time T is about 170 msec, and the pk-pk voltage is just about 4 volts.

> I need to know how much it increments per step.

This is almost certainly the output of a D/A converter. You'll need to check the paper to find out how many steps are being displayed. From the look of the trace, especially the magnified portion, it looks like the step time is about 4 msec/step. That would give you a total of about 42 steps in 4 volts, or about 100 mV per step.